# Trying to make a plot of eigenvalues (root locus) of a characteristic equation as one variable is increased but getting a blank plot?

Tags: python, matlab

Can't at all see why I'm not getting anything back? Trying to plot eigenvalues.

```
A2 = m*J;
A1 = J*((Cf+Cr)/U)+m*(((Cf*Lf^2)+(Cr*Lr^2))/U^2);
A0 = ((Cf+Cr)/U)*(((Cf*Lf^2)+(Cr*Lr^2))/U)-m*(Cf*Lf-Cr*Lr)-((Cf*Lf-Cr*Lr^2)/U^2);

%loop through values of U (forward velocity) to find all eigenvalues
 for U = 1:80
     lambda = (-A1+sqrt(A1^2-4*A0*A2))/(2*A2);
     plot(real(lambda), imag(lambda));
 end
```

When run, the script just returns a blank argan diagram. Using Matlab [R2018b]

Comment: You are dividing by 0, `U = 0`, you define  `A1, A0` using `/U^2`, hence `A1, A0` are `inf`

Comment: @Nathan good spot, having deleted it I at least get complex values for lambda now but still nothing on my graph, am I using plot() correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, as already stated, is that you are dividing by 0, `U = 0`, you define `A1, A0` using `/U^2`, hence `A1, A0` are `inf`

Another problem is that you do not use `hold on` (more info [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)). This means that you overwrite the plot each time, ending up with a final plot of just one point.

To be better able to see this point you can increase the markersize, as said [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6537-how-do-i-change-the-marker-size-for-a-plot). This makes the points better visible, e.g.: `plot(real(lambda), imag(lambda),'o','MarkerSize',12);` results in data points marked with an circle of size 12

EDIT: further improvements

What is also better to do is not plotting in the loop, then you would not even need the `hold on`. So for example:

```
 maxidx = 80;
 lambda = zeros(1,maxidx);
 for U = 1:maxidx 
     lambda(U) = (-A1+sqrt(A1^2-4*A0*A2))/(2*A2);
 end

plot(real(lambda), imag(lambda),'o','MarkerSize',12);
title('Root Locus as Speed is Increased')
xlabel('real')
ylabel('imaginary')
```

BTW you will end up with just one point, since `A0, A1, A2`are constant

Comment: Awesome, taking the plot outside the loop does look much cleaner. Still lost as to why it's only returning the value of lambda when U is at maxidx and not at each interval between 1:maxidx, otherwise why loop at all? 

Surely as A1 and A0 are dependent on U I should be getting different values each time?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: @mfarrell: you need to re-compute `A0` and `A1` inside the loop. Changing the value of `U` doesn’t automatically trigger a re-computation of your other variables.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Bingo, that's done just the trick. Thanks for your help.